# How would I go about creating a div that filled the whole screen, with content under it

Tags: html, css

Here is an example of what im looking at doing.
http://www.childrens2012.org/

Sort of background image/colour that fills the entire screen regardless of size, however when you scroll down you have more content.

I got it working for colours

```
#tester{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background-color: blue;}
```

However when I tired to use a background image i keep running into trouble if i position it absoulte then the content below comes up and it just doesnt seem to work.

here is what ive got

```
width:100%;
height:100%;
background: url(../images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
 background-size: cover;
 position:absolute;
```

any ideas?

Comment: please provide complete codes pls. so that it would be easier to help you.:)

Comment: Switch `position`to fixed, and set `0` for each of the four "corners" (top, right, bottom, left).

Answer (score 1):

Here's a question: `height:100%`.. 100% of what?

Add this:

```
body, html {
  height:100%;
}
```

and it should work.

http://jsbin.com/evifeh/1/edit

Comment: the image doesnt scoll up, the content covers it. In the example I gave the image scrolls up like content does, however in your example the image is fixed on the page and the content covers it when you scroll down. I hope 'm making sense here haha

Comment: and its 100% of the exact height of the browser, regardless of whether its mobile or 1080px or 700px or anything in between.

Comment: @Ghozt Then remove the `fixed` positioning on the image and it'll scroll up. Re your second comment: it becomes that way when you set body,html's height to 100%.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you want to achieve. The given example and your example code differ from handling the image.

To give you another solution:

```
#tester{ margin-top: 100% }
```